# aws api gateway mapping template for binary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send a binary file and string parameters to AWS API Gateway.

this is the mapping template that is on API Gateway POST:

```
{
    "imageFile" : $input.params('imageFile'),
    "purdueUsername" : $input.params('purdueUsername'),
    "description" : $input.params('description'),
    "price" : $input.params('price'),
    "longitude" : $input.params('longitude'),
    "latitude" : $input.params('latitude'),
    "category" : $input.params('category'),
}
```

Making a post request results in this:
[image]

When I try this

```
{
    "imageFile" : "$input.params('imageFile')",
    "purdueUsername" : "$input.params('purdueUsername')",
    "description" : "$input.params('description')",
    "price" : "$input.params('price')",
    "longitude" : "$input.params('longitude')",
    "latitude" : "$input.params('latitude')",
    "category" : "$input.params('category')",
}
```

I am getting empty parameters. The api is not receiving the parameters I am sending through POST request.

[image]

How should I change the mapping template?
Note: When I only try to have imageFile in the mapping template and only send binary file without extra parameters it works completely fine.

```
{
"imageFile" : "$input.body"
}
```

However, I want to be able to send other parameters beside the binary file.

Answer (score 2):

this is how I solved the problem. I am sending the binary file in the body of the POST request and the other parameters as a header.

this is the mapping template I put on the AWS API Gateway

```
{
    "purdueUsername" : "$input.params('purdueUsername')",
    "description" : "$input.params('description')",
    "price" : "$input.params('price')",
    "longitude" : "$input.params('longitude')",
    "latitude" : "$input.params('latitude')",
    "category" : "$input.params('category')",
    "isbnNumber" : "$input.params('isbnNumber')",
    "imageFile" : "$input.body"
}
```